# Let $T$ a linear operator. $T$ is bounded then ker($T$) is closed.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $T$ a linear operator. $T$ is bounded then ker($T$) is closed.

**My attempt:**

Let $\{x_n\}\subset \ker(T)$.

As $T$ is bounded then exists $M>0$ such that $||T(x_n)||_y\leq M.||x_n||$

Note that $T(x_n)=0$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

then $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}T(x_n)=0$

Here i'm stuck. can someone help me?

Comment: Can you use 'linear + bounded $\implies$ continuous?'

Comment: @Leonardo no, i can't.

Answer (score 1):

Continuing with your proof: suppose $x_n \in \text{ker}T$  converges to $x$. You have to show that $x \in \text{ker}T$. Since $T$ is linear and bounded then it is also continuous, therefore sequentially continuous, therefore the limit of $T(x_n)$ is $T(x)$, and it must be zero, since for all $n$ you have $T(x_n)=0$. So the claim follows.

Or also $\text{ker}T=T^{-1}(\{0\})$. But $\{0\}$ is closed, then so is  $\text{ker}T=T^{-1}(\{0\})$, as $T$ Is continuous (because linear and bounded)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $lim_nx_n=0$, we have $\|T(x_n)\|\leq M\|x_n\|$ since $lim_nM\|x_n\|=0$, we deduce that $lim_n\|T(x_n)\|=0$.

In general let $x=lim_nx_n, T(x_n)=0, lim_n(x_n-x)=0$ implies that $lim_nT(x_n-x)=T(x)=0$.

Comment: I don't see why $\lim_n M \left\lVert x_n\right\rVert = 0.$ can you clarify this please?